# How to change Char array value in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

**I want to change the value of char data**
/* Error is while changing default value, Is there any another way */

```
char name[]="Ronaldo";
int choice='0';

    printf("Select Player");
    printf("1.Messi\n 2.Suarez\n 3.Neymer\n 4.Dembele\n");
    switch(choice)
    case 1:
            printf("Messi is Selected");

            **Error Position**

            name="Messi";
            printf("Player changd to %s",name);
            break;

    case 5:
            printf("Exit");
            name="Muller";
            exit(1)
```

*Changing Player name*

Comment: error: assignment to expression with array type

Comment: You are assigning a character to an integer... `int choice='0';` This is the first mistake... Instead write `int choice=0;` Also consider using `puts()` instead of `printf()` if you are printing text which is always the same.

Comment: @71GA That's not necessarily a mistake. It's legal C code at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1.

```
name="Messi";
```

You can´t assign a `char` array with a string unless at its initialization, which is done with:

```
char name[]="Ronaldo";
```

Rather use `strcpy()` (Header `string.h`) -> `strcpy(name,"Messi");` instead.

Consider that the array `name` needs to be capable of holding the new-assigned string + the null terminator, which is in this case provided because the string `"Ronaldo"` has more characters than any of the following. If that would not be the case you have to define `name` with an appropriate amount of characters or choose a name which is bigger than anyone else or the program would cause an overflow of data in memory.

#### 2.

Note that the `switch` statement doesn´t make sense if `choice` is always `0` because you have never read input for `choice`.

Also the `cases` to the `switch` are not enclosed by `{` and `}` which should give you a compilation error.

#### 3.

`choice` is initialized by a character. While this is permissible, it does not make sense in this case and confuses readers of your code. Rather use `int choice = 0;`

---

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char name[]="Ronaldo";
    int choice=0;

    printf("Select Player\n");
    printf("1.Messi\n2.Suarez\n3.Neymar\n4.Dembele\n5.Muller\n\n");

    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {

    case 1:
            printf("\nMessi is Selected");
            strcpy(name,"Messi");

            break;


    case 2:
            printf("\nSuarez is Selected");
            strcpy(name,"Suarez");

            break;


    case 3:
            printf("\nNeymar is Selected");
            strcpy(name,"Neymar");

            break;    

    case 4:
            printf("\nDembele is Selected");
            strcpy(name,"Dembele");

            break;    


    case 5:
            printf("\nMuller is Selected");
            strcpy(name,"Muller"); 
           
            break;               

    default:
            printf("Exit");
            exit(1);
    } 

    printf("\nPlayer changed to %s",name);   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
/a.out
Select Player  
1.Messi      
2.Suarez      
3.Neymar             
4.Dembele 
5.Muller 
  
2        // Input from User

Suarez is Selected               
Player changed to Suarez
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
char name[]="Ronaldo";
```

gives you an array of chars. **That's not what you want** because an array of char doesn't allow simple assignment. For char arrays you need to use `strcpy`.

However - **what you want is a pointer to char** - like:

```
char* name="Ronaldo";
```

Then you can do simple assignments like:

```
char* name="Ronaldo";
printf("My player is %s\n", name);
name = "Eriksen";
printf("My player is %s\n", name);
```

A char-pointer can be directly assigned to point to any string literal.

Besides that you never get any user input.

And notice that `switch` statement has a `default`- like:

```
switch(choice)
{
    case 1:
        // do some things for input 1
    break;

    case 2:
        // do some things for input 2
    break;

    default:
        // do some things for all other values
    break;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I deleted my comment. So to not get dangling string literals anywhere in memory, the only way is probably to assign each character and the terminating null character individually.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Correct but that will probably end up using even more memory than the "dangling" string literals. I haven't tested it - it's just my guess.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `main()` and a lot of other things... It could work like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){

char name[20] = "Ronaldo";
int choice;

    printf("Select Player:\n\n");
    printf("\t1.Messi\n\t2.Suarez\n\t3.Neymer\n\t4.Dembele\n\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice){
    case 1:
            strcpy(name, "Messi");
            printf("\t%s is selected...\n", name);
            break;

    case 2:
            strcpy(name, "Suarez");
            printf("\t%s is selected...\n", name);
            break;

    case 3:
            strcpy(name, "Neymer");
            printf("\t%s is selected...\n", name);
            break;

    case 4:
            strcpy(name, "Dembele");
            printf("\t%s is selected...\n", name);
            break;

    default:
            puts("\tWrong selection");
    }

return(0);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several errors in your code :

> char name[]="Ronaldo";
   
This creates character array which                          should have predefined length.

> int choice='0';
   
Integer type cannot store '0'

First correct them and then give more information about what you are looking for.

Comment: First, `char name[]="Ronaldo";` is equal to `char name [8]; strcpy(name, "Ronaldo");` - the compiler automatically determines the length - so 1. is not true. Second, it is actually permissible to assign an `int` with a character, so "*Integer type cannot store '0'*" is wrong.